# SVG get current animation progress (SMIL) in <path>: stroke-dashoffset

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, smil

I am having very simple animation of `path` element. Animation applies to `stroke-dashoffset` attribute. Problem that I am facing is that I can't get animation progress after pause animation. 
Here is my SVG code and javascript which actually do nothing but pause and start animation:

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  $('.svg')[0].pauseAnimations();
  
  // get current stroke-dashoffset value ??
  // $('#stroke')[0]['stroke-dashoffset'].animVal  - it doesn't work

  $('.svg')[0].unpauseAnimations();
}, 500); // 500 is testing value (!) it can be anything
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" class="svg">
  <path d="M47.488,10.079A40,40,0,0,0,16.302,71.551"  id="stroke" style="stroke-width: 10px; fill: none; stroke: #333;" stroke-dasharray="83.07828521728516px 83.07828521728516px" stroke-dashoffset="-83.07828521728516px">
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" id="anim2" dur="1000ms" from="-83.07828521728516px" to="-39.095663631663605" fill="freeze"></animate>
 </path>
</svg>
```

I know how to get animation progress when using `<circle>` element: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17217470/1736186 but I don't know how to get `stroke-dashoffset` value in `<path>`.

I can get it done by combining timeout with min/max `stroke-dashoffset` and calculate approximate progress, but I believe (hope) I am missing something and it can be done easily with `animVal`. 
So please don't post an answer with that kind of solution, because I know how to do it by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite interesting, I didn't know there weren't an `animVal` for all animatable attributes, but it seems that `stroke-dashoffset` attribute, is directly converted to its style equivalent.

So for your problem, a simple solution is to request the computed style of your element :

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  $('.svg')[0].pauseAnimations();
  
  // get current stroke-dashoffset value
  console.log( getComputedStyle($('#stroke')[0]).strokeDashoffset );

  $('.svg')[0].unpauseAnimations();
}, 500); // 500 is testing value (!) it can be anything
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" class="svg">
  <path d="M47.488,10.079A40,40,0,0,0,16.302,71.551"  id="stroke" style="stroke-width: 10px; fill: none; stroke: #333;" stroke-dasharray="83.07828521728516px 83.07828521728516px" stroke-dashoffset="-83.07828521728516px">
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" id="anim2" dur="1000ms" from="-83.07828521728516px" to="-39.095663631663605" fill="freeze"></animate>
 </path>
</svg>
```

Comment: By the way I don't know where did the `px` gone in FF's stringification...