# JavaScript - SVG animation position changed event

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to make a simple game of pong using SVGs and vanilla JavaScript. The issue that I'm running into is, how can I bind an event to determine when the position of the ball has moved? So for example, is there anything like:

```
document.getElementById("ball").getAttribute("cx").onChange = ...;
```

The code that I've currently built is:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  
}

window.onkeydown = function(e){
  /*
  Player 1:
  up    -> 38
  down  -> 40
  */
  var increment = 0;
  
  if (e.keyCode === 38 || e.keyCode === 40) {
    increment = 5;
    
    if (e.keyCode === 38) {
      increment = -increment;
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("paddle1").setAttribute("y", parseFloat(document.getElementById("paddle1").getAttribute("y")) + increment);
};

window.onmousemove = function(e) {
  // Player2: Based on the y position of the mouse
  document.getElementById("paddle2").setAttribute("y", e.clientY);
}
```

```html
<svg width="576px" height="300px">
  <!-- background -->
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="576" height="300" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
  
  <!-- ball -->
  <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="5" fill="white" id="ball">
    <animateMotion path="M 0 150 H 576 Z" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>
  
  <!-- mid-point -->
  <line stroke-dasharray="5, 10" x1="287.5" y1="1" x2="287.5" y2="300"  stroke="white" stroke-width="1" />
  
  <!-- scores -->
  <text x="261" y="27" font-family="monospace" font-size="22px" fill="white" id="score1">0</text>
  <text x="298" y="27" font-family="monospace" font-size="22px" fill="white" id="score2">0</text>
    
  <!-- paddles -->
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="5" height="25" stroke="white" stroke-width="1" fill="white" id="paddle1" />
  <rect x="561" y="10" width="5" height="25" stroke="white" stroke-width="1" fill="white" id="paddle2" />
  
</svg>
```

Please keep in mind that while I have a fairly extensive JavaScript background, this is my first jump into SVGs.

Comment: Are you open to use plugin if yes then snap svg is nice plugin to do so. It returns every value you require. Or you can use gsap as well.

Comment: @UllasHunka - If this were actual development, then I would be open to a plugin. However, since this is for learning purposes, I'd prefer to stick with vanilla JS.

Comment: @David I dont think it's possible when animateMotion is present, animateMotion runs in a separate thread, so getting the values from that is not possible. If you can generate that animation through Javascript then it's possible to detect the change through MutationObserver.

Comment: If you are really doing a pong, you won't be using animateMotion very long... You'll probably find it's way easier to control the position and direction of the ball entirely from your js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does not seem to be an event emitted upon a change of an animated value, not even with a coarse granularity (ie. at given percentages of the animation completed).

However, the current animated values can be queried, so calling a pseudo-handler in regular intervals allows to keep track of the animation's progress within reasonable limits.

The following proof-of-concept standalone svg complements and modifies the code from the question:

- define an interval handler to write the current x position of the ball to the console
- set up the interval handler in the onLoad handler
- Redefine the animation using the `animate` element

```svg
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    viewBox="0 0 1000 500"
    width="1150px" height="600px"
>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function cb_ball ( pdom_ball ) {
            console.log ( `attr 'cx': '${pdom_ball.cx.animVal.value}'.`);
        } // cb_ball

        window.onload = function() {
            let dom_ball = document.getElementById("ball")
              ;

            setInterval ( () => { cb_ball ( dom_ball ); }, 100 );
        }

        window.onkeydown = function(e){
            /*
                Player 1:
                    up    -> 38
                    down  -> 40
            */
            var increment = 0;

            if (e.keyCode === 38 || e.keyCode === 40) {
                increment = 5;

                if (e.keyCode === 38) {
                    increment = -increment;
                }
            }

            document.getElementById("paddle1").setAttribute("y", parseFloat(document.getElementById("paddle1").getAttribute("y")) + increment);
        };

        window.onmousemove = function(e) {
            // Player2: Based on the y position of the mouse
            document.getElementById("paddle2").setAttribute("y", e.clientY);
        }
    </script>

    <!-- background -->
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="576" height="300" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />

    <!-- ball -->
    <circle cx="0" cy="150" r="5" fill="white" id="ball">
        <!-- was: animateMotion path="M 0 150 H 576 Z" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" /-->
        <animate id="ball-animation"
            attributeName="cx"
            attributeType="XML"
            values = "0;285;570;285;0"
            keyTimes="0;0.25;0.5;0.75;1"
            calcMode="linear"
            dur="5s"
            repeatCount="indefinite"
        />
    </circle>

    <!-- mid-point -->
    <line stroke-dasharray="5, 10" x1="287.5" y1="1" x2="287.5" y2="300"  stroke="white" stroke-width="1" />

    <!-- scores -->
    <text x="261" y="27" font-family="monospace" font-size="22px" fill="white" id="score1">0</text>
    <text x="298" y="27" font-family="monospace" font-size="22px" fill="white" id="score2">0</text>

    <!-- paddles -->
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="5" height="25" stroke="white" stroke-width="1" fill="white" id="paddle1" />
    <rect x="561" y="10" width="5" height="25" stroke="white" stroke-width="1" fill="white" id="paddle2" />
</svg>
```

**References**

The solution is based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217326/catch-changes-on-svg-element-circle-and-change-attributes-elsewhere-via-js) and the following standards documents:

- [`animateMotion`element](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#AnimateMotionElement)
- [SVG IDL](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/idl.html)
- [SVGAnimatedLength](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#InterfaceSVGAnimatedLength)

**Alternatives**

[anime.js](https://github.com/juliangarnier/anime) appears to be a animation library that would suit needs outlined in the question (cf. [this section](https://github.com/juliangarnier/anime#callbacks)), in partiucular for authors with a solid js background (I have no affiliation neither with the library nor the author).

Comment: As mentioned in the SVG not emitting any event. Is there any possibility that in next build it's going to come? Upvoting as its the only solution I can see.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer since I feel as though this will be the best that it gets. Thank you so much for your contribution.